# Postfix smtp mail loging

Tags: smtp, postfix, proxy, logging

Google fails me... Is there a way without modifying Postfix code to get copies of emails sent via smtpd server? Anything will do - text file, pipe, local socket. I just need Postfix giving me time, sender, receiver, body including attachments, if there are any.

P.S. If there is SMTP proxy that run on Linux and can do this - name of it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
J

Comment: my issue resolve kindly [check answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/987962/491178)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the configuration directives [always_bcc](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#always_bcc), [recipient_bcc_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps) or [sender_bcc_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_bcc_maps).

Comment: +1 for always_bcc.  Been using it with no problems and no noticeable extra load to the server.

Comment: +1 as well, always_bcc has worked for 2+ years for my company, Gotta love people who say they never recieved an email, when they sure did.  :)

Answer (score 0):

There's someting in [ASSP](http://assp.sourceforge.net/) that could fit your needs, you can forward all ham mails to one addresses and all spam mails also.